# OpenCV: Convert Mat to 3D Image Array

Tags: c++, opencv

I am capturing frames from a video source and want to output them as files in, for example, BMP format.

What I would like to know is a) is there built in functionality for this, and b) if not, how do I get the RGB values for each of the pixels in each frame represented by a Mat object?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) See [`imwrite`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite) (on the same page of the documentation as the video capture stuff)

b) If you do want to get RGB values from a Mat object, see [the Mat documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?#mat), which discusses element access in detail - in summary, `M.at<datatype>(i,j)` or `M.data[ M.step[0]*i + M.step[1]*j ]` -- the latter may differ depending on your version of OpenCV, consult the corresponding documentation page.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Regarding b), shouldn't the data be a 3D array (with the third dimension being RGB)? However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Also, how do I know the type of the elements? Thanks again.